# Undefined it is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting error in my code:

This is error line : *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*
This line is: `$('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function()`

I did some research in the site. I do not understand many things from those described.
What is this problem and how can i fixed it anyone can help me?

```
$('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function()           
{ 
var values=$("#uploadvalues").val();
$("#previeww").html('<img src="wall_icons/loader.gif"/>');
$("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '.resim-onizleme', 
     beforeSubmit:function(){ 
     $("#imageloadstatus").show();
     $("#imageloadbutton").show();
     }, 
    success:function(){ 
     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
     $("#imageloadbutton").show();
    }, 
    error:function(){ 
     $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
     $("#imageloadbutton").show();
    } }).submit();

var X=$('.preview').attr('id');
var Z= X+','+values;
if(Z!='undefined,')
{
$("#uploadvalues").val(Z);
}

});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/die/: *"version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are deprecated. Try change it to

```
$('#photoimg').off('click').on('change', function() ...
```

If this error happens everywhere on the page, then perhaps it is missing the jQuery library script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>js/jquery.wallform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Now same error will come in this line: `$("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '.resim-onizleme',`

Comment: Can you add the code where you implement <script src="xxx for the jQuery? It could be the issue.

Comment: `<script src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>js/jquery.wallform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: where is your jQuery script?

Comment: Can you tell me how it happened ?

Comment: You mean why it happened? You cannot use a method that is not defined. In this case, .on() or .off() and so on, those methods are specified in the jQuery javascript file so you must include the scripts before using them. hope this helps